# Javascript not throwing any errors for using undefined variables/functions in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am using create-react-app for some personal purposes. Javascript for some reason doesn't throw any error or warning at all when -

1. Import is not done or is wrong.
2. Function or variable that is being used has not been defined.

It is simply assigning any unknown thing to any and taking it. Why is this happening and what is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are describing is likely due to the fact that create-react-app uses Babel to transpile your code to support older browsers that may not support certain features of modern JavaScript. This process can sometimes mask certain errors or warnings that would otherwise be caught by the JavaScript engine.

To address the issues you mentioned, you can use a linter like ESLint to enforce coding standards and catch potential errors before running your code. ESLint can also be configured to integrate with your development environment, such as in VS Code, to show errors and warnings in real-time as you write code.

For example, to catch undefined variables, you can use the no-undef rule in ESLint. To catch missing imports, you can use the import/no-unresolved rule. To catch assigning unknown things, you can use the no-unused-vars rule.

To get started with ESLint in a create-react-app project, you can install the eslint and eslint-plugin-react packages and then create a .eslintrc file to configure ESLint. You can also use an existing ESLint configuration like the Airbnb JavaScript style guide.

Once you have ESLint set up, you can run it as part of your build process or integrate it with your development environment to see errors and warnings in real-time. This will help you catch potential issues earlier in the development process and write more reliable code.